# sample space and probability

Tags: probability

The laboratories at a major pharmaceuticals company are studying four drugs to see whether any one of them is an effective treatment for diabetes.Each drug will either be effective or ineffective .the drugs are A, B, C, D.
A researcher wants to consider the possible groups of drugs that will turn out to be effective.list all of the outcomes in the sample space that shows groups of effective drugs

I don't know how to proceed with this and what notation to use. I know what sample space will be, I just don't know how to put it into symbols.I guess the answer would be only one effective, two effective, three effective and all four effective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 Effective Drugs :

1 Effective Drug: A, B, C, D

2 Effective Drugs: AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD

3 Effective Drugs: ABC, ABD, ACD, BCD

4 Effective Drugs: ABCD

I think that's how to write the sample space

Comment: so to write the sample space of all outcomes should i write it like this
S=  {{A}, {B}, {C}, {D},{AB}, {AC}, {AD}, {BC}, {BD}, {CD},{ABC}, {ABD}, {ACD}, {BCD},{ABCD}}  ??

Comment: well, you just want to write every possible outcome, so yes the format should work

Comment: is this format correct S= {{A}, {B}, {C}, {D},{AB}, {AC}, {AD}, {BC}, {BD}, {CD},{ABC}, {ABD}, {ACD}, {BCD},{ABCD}} ?